# Inserting javascript values into erb code

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, maps, erb

I have a js.erb template with the following code:

```
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(<%= session[:lat] %>, <%= session[:lng] %>);
```

I'm now trying to do the opposite (insert javascript into ruby):

```
<% session[:lat] = javascript_tag("document.write(location.lat());") %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're missing the point of Javascript.

Ruby code (`<% .. %>` parts in your examples) is run on the server.

Javascript code (`var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(10, 20);` and `document.write(location.lat());`) is executed in the browser.
It's also executed *after* ruby code, when server has processed request and generated result page already.

If you want to know value of `location.lat()` on the server, you'll have to send it from the browser to the server in AJAX request. Any popular Javascript library will help with that.

Comment: @DanS Regarding your edit... Browser knows some value (`location.lat()`) and you want server to know it to. It means, you have to send some kind of request to the server. Ajax or not.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try `<%= raw [ruby/rails code] %>`
This link may help: http://groups.google.com/group/rubyonrails-talk/browse_thread/thread/a160d9c2e55cfe36